# How do dismiss keyboard on .searchable while search bar is still focused?. [SwiftUI]

Tags: ios, swiftui, keyboard, dismiss, searchable

I added `.searchable` and it is working fine. But I want to show another view while the search is still focused and on the navigation bar.

If I use

`@Environment(\.dismissSearch) private var dismissSearch`

It will completely dismiss the search and clean the search text. I don't want that to happen.

By clicking `Search` button on keyboard, it will dismiss the keyboard. But I want to do it programmatically.

so any workaround to dismiss the keyboard while search bar is still focused?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your code

```swift
extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        let resign = #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder)
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(resign, to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to call `hideKeyboard()` from within any view and that will dismiss the keyboard.